# FAQ for Philosophy.SE

Tags: discussion, faq, allowed-topics, community

## Community FAQ

**For Philosophy.SE, a site in the Stack Exchange 2.0 network**

You may also wish to review [the community FAQ for all sites in the StackExchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

### Content

### Asking questions

- [What is this site about?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/what-is-this-site-about)
- [What is considered off-topic?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-is-considered-off-topic)
- [Is thinking (and discussion) disallowed on the Philosophy site?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3925/is-thinking-and-discussion-disallowed-on-the-philosophy-site?)
- [Should we restrict this site to academic questions only, or target a more casual audience?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-we-restrict-this-site-to-academic-questions-only-or-target-a-more-casual)
- [Do questions have to be answerable?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/do-questions-have-to-be-answerable)

### Answering questions

- [Should I express my own opinions?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379/are-we-allowed-to-express-our-own-opinions) (See also: [Should answers be cited?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/should-answers-be-cited))
- [Should this site be restricted to academic answers only?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-this-site-be-restricted-to-academic-answers-only) (See also: [Are amateurs with little knowledge of philosophy welcome?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329/are-amateur-users-that-have-little-knowledge-about-philosophy-not-ideal-for-ph))
- [Should I post a new answer to a question that already has an accepted answer?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320/should-i-post-a-new-answer-to-a-question-that-already-has-an-accepted-answer)

### Accepting answers

- [What are the criteria for marking an answer correct?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-is-the-criteria-for-marking-answers-as-correct-in-philosophy)

### Working with posts

- [I've got edit privileges! Now what?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/i-have-editor-privileges-now-should-i-use-them)

### Comments

- [How to handle discussions? ("Not in comments, please")](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/not-in-comments-please-how-to-handle-interesting-discussions)

### Tagging

- [How should we tag questions?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/how-should-we-tag-questions)

### Reputation, badges, and voting

- [Vote early, vote often!](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/vote-early-vote-often)

### Moderation

- [Who are the moderators, and what if they run amok?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/81) (see also: [Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/moderator-pro-tem-announcement))

### Other

- [How can we promote Philosophy StackExchange?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-can-we-promote-philosophy-stack-exchange)

### External links

Original links from meta.SO's community FAQ for sites in the StackExchange 2.0 network:

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Help Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)
- [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)
- [How to Ask by Jon Skeet](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
- [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
- [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)
- [Ten Simple Rules for Getting Help from Online Scientific Communities](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info:doi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002202)

---

#### How can a question be added to this FAQ?

- **Link back** to this index.  Paste this at the end of the question:

  `[Return to FAQ index](/q/362)`
- Tag as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).  When a post seems to hit a mature state, it will have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) added by a moderator.
- Flag for a moderator to mark **community wiki**.  Any FAQ post not yet community wiki should be made into a community wiki.
- Add a link in the above table of contents.
- Ask only the question, stated plainly and simply, in the question body. The answer goes in an answer.