# Some of my posts aren't listed in "Activity"

Tags: support, recent-activity

I haven't found an answer to this question in Help. But maybe someone can point me to it. I'd like to know why some of my posts do appear in my Activity page, and some don't. I posted four answers to other people's questions within a few hours of each other. Two of the posts are in Activity. The other two aren't. I'm just wondering what the reason for that would be.

Answer (score 2):

At least one of those answers was deleted. It was an answer to [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64163/is-there-a-word-for-the-type-of-rhetorical-strategy-where-you-distract-from-the/). Not sure if you can see the deleted answer there yourself, but users with 2k+ rep can still see it. I voted to delete the answer (and it was eventually deleted by a moderator), because it didn't really answer the question, didn't contain any useful information, and involved an attack on the OP.

Please see: [How do I write a good answer?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and the [FAQ for Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362/faq-for-philosophy-se).